# React Router: Redirect to a different component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

There are two main links on the landing page and then when user clicks on the option it should redirect to that component and **not render** the component below in the same page.

But, rather than going to the next page, the component is displayed below like a navbar.

```
const MainRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
      <div className='routes'>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to='/team-member'>Team Member</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/moderator'>Moderator</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <Route path='/team-member' component={TeamMember} />
        <Route path='/moderator' component={Moderator} />
      </div>
    </ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <MainRoutes />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your routes in [Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch):

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/team-member' component={TeamMember} />
  <Route exact path='/moderator' component={Moderator} />
</Switch>
```

As `Switch` renders the first child `<Route>` that matches the location. Also, it renders a route *exclusively* (which you need).

#### Edit:

If you don't want to show `NavBar` at other components but only at index route `/`, you can do this:

```
const MainRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div className="routes">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={NavBar} />
          <Route exact path="/team-member" component={TeamMember} />
          <Route exact path="/moderator" component={Moderator} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  )
}
```

**NavBar:**

```
function NavBar() {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/team-member">Team Member</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/moderator">Moderator</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Comment: doing so, when I click on the route the component is rendered right below it rather than going on a different page plus the two routes are still displayed on the page.